# Making an R loop to find bins more appropriately R

Tags: r

I wrote a little loop to find which 'bin' a number is within but I feel like it's quite pythonic and not very R. Is there a more appropriate way to do this, or is it normal?

```
  binLimits <- seq(0, 70, 10)
  binNames <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")

  pos <- 45

  # Find which bin pos is in
  n <-0
  for (i in binLimits){
    if (pos < i){
      pos.bin <- binNames[n]
      break
    }
    n <- n+1 
  }

 print (pos)
  [1] "E"
```

I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: If your bins are regularly spaced (as they are here) then you can do it by subtracting the lower bin edge and dividing by the bin width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findInterval` is made for this task:

```
binNames[findInterval(45,binLimits)]
[1] "E"
```

Or `cut`:

```
cut(45,binLimits,binNames)
[1] E
Levels: A B C D E F G
```

Both functions are vectorised so you don't need any loops.

Comment: Fantastic! So simple! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use : 
`tail(binNames[binLimits<=pos],1)`